# Div is rendering as empty

Tags: android, css

I have a page that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="inner">
                <img width="300" height="250" src="someimage.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS styling is this:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#outer {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

I'm getting a lot of strange behavior:

1. On the initial load of the webpage in a WebView, all I see is a blue line. It's like there's no image in the `inner` div.
2. On the first refresh, the WebView will slowly expand to 100% height. It slowly reveals `someimage.jpg`. It's like an animation of the `outer` div as it slowly realizes it needs to take up the whole screen.
3. On all subsequent refreshes, the expanding animation doesn't happen. Everything looks fine.

What's going on in the first two loads of the webpage?

The other weird thing is that if I don't have that blue border, #2 and #3 don't happen. That is, I'm stuck with just a blue line which is really the blue border of a collapsed `div`. I don't understand why I need the border to make the contents of the `inner` div to show up.

Note that I'm using the same WebView for all the loads. That is, it's just calling `WebView#loadUrl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured why it was "expanding" the way it was: I wasn't adding the WebView with any layout parameters! It seems that all of my problems stemmed from this little detail.